# Reverse geocoding limits

Tags: objective-c, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I want to the get the country code top-level domain using latitude and longitude. I have tried google reverse geocoding and it worked really well. Unfortunately I discovered that there is a daily limit which is a problem for me because I would like to use it often as well as my users.

Does anyone have any recommendations? Is there a free reverse geocoding that I can install locally and use it publicly?

Comment: What API are you using can you paste some code?

Answer (score 1):

You could use OSM for geocoding, for example [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim). Ether [install](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation) it yourself or use a public instance. Keep in mind that OSM's official instance runs on donated resources and has a rather strict [usage policy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim_usage_policy). But if you don't want to install your own instance you can choose a [third party provider](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim_usage_policy#Alternatives_.2F_Third-party_providers) which usually have less strict policies.

Comment: A local installation? No idea, probably not without hassle.

Comment: so windows is better for this task??

Comment: Please read the installation instructions. You will need Linux, either on your host or in a VM.

Answer (score 0):

**A simple and free option for reverse geocoding very large datasets is to:**

1. Download the relevant GIS data from: [DIVA-GIS](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata).
2. Load GIS data into [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) as the  first layer.
3. Load in the coordinate points (latitude and longitude) as the second layer.
4. Join the two layers from the menu by going to 'Vector' -> 'Data Management Tools' -> Join Attributes By Location', then save the file as a Shapefile.

This will add data address data to your geopoints, down to the granularity of the GIS file used.

**Finally, if you need to export the data as a CSV:**

5. Add the [MMQGIS](http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/) plugin to QGIS
6. Click the MMQGIS menu, 'Import / Export' -> 'Geometry Export to CSV file'.